# Disable strong parameters for a specific action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a serious problem with strong parameters. Its working pretty well in my about 200 actions but in one it doesn't because I'm working very dynamic with the parameters there and I also cant change it because of the applications design.

So I want to disable strong parameters validation in just this specific action. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why you can not use `if` in this specific place???

Comment: Because I dont know how the params will be named. My action is based on metaprogramming...

Answer (score 22):

Strong parameters overrides the `params` method in `ActionController::Base`. You can simply override it and set it back to what you want yourself.

So this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def params
    request.parameters
  end
end
```

Will effectively disable strong parameters for all actions in your controller. You only wanted to disable it for a particular action though so you could do that with:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :use_unsafe_params, only: [:particular_action]

  def params
    @_dangerous_params || super
  end

  def particular_action
    # My params is unsafe
  end

  def normal_action
    # my params is safe
  end

  private

  def use_unsafe_params
    @_dangerous_params = request.parameters
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Not too sure if this is best practice but for Rails 5 I just use `request.params` instead of `params` anytime I want to skip strong params.

So instead of something like:

```rb
post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

I use:

```rb
post = Post.new(request.params[:post])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.permit!` to whitelist any keys in a hash.

```
params.require(:something).permit!
```

However this should be treated as an extreme code smell and a security risk.

Nested hashes can be whitelisted with this trick:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, data: params[:product][:data].try(:keys))
```

Comment: This wont work for me because the name of the params isn't defined staticly they are defined by the displayed object. I know this sounds like a big security hole but I implemented security mechanisms in the method logic. I really need to turn strong parameters off in one action

Comment: The only way I can think of using `config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters` but that is done on a per-app basis. Not per action.

Comment: Yes for the develoment mode I disabled strong parameters but of cause I can't do this in production mode

Comment: You could create some kind of function that recursively walks the params hash and whitelists it. But I can't really give you an example since I have no idea what your controller looks like.

Comment: I think its easier to modify the strong parameters gem in a way that allows disabeling the gem action specific

Comment: Yeah but hacking core is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79314/discussion-between-maxcal-and-davidb).